# Local APIC registers mapped in memory contain just 1's

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86

I'm trying to write some code for a Linux kernel module that can read from and write to the local APIC on x86. I'm using the code snippet below to read from the Interrupt Command Register:

```
printk(KERN_ERR "APIC %p %d", (int32_t *)(APIC_BASE + 0x300), 
                              *(volatile int32_t *)(APIC_BASE + 0x300));
```

This is the output, which never changes:

```
APIC ffffffffff5f5300 -1
```

Since I'm printing out a signed 32-bit integer, `-1` indicates that the 32 bits I read were all 1's. This is unexpected since (to my understanding) bit 11 (the destination mode bit) needs to be 0 before I can write to the local APIC to send an IPI.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly? Are there any initialization steps that I need to take?

Comment: A few things to check: Is the APIC_BASE correct? Is the APIC region mapped? Is x2APIC **not** enabled? (Bit 10 of IA32_APIC_BASE should be 0). Note that the Destination mode bit (bit 11 of ICR) is not an indicator of a pending IPI (bit 12, Delivery Status, is).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Hi Margaret - thank you so much for your comment. It actually does appear that the computer has an x2APIC, so I'm looking into writing the APIC code to use MSRs rather than memory-mapped registers. I'll post an update once this is complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my computer is equipped with a newer x2APIC, rather than an xAPIC. x2APICs use MSRs to send IPIs rather than memory-mapped registers, which is what xAPICs use. Thus, the memory I was reading at `APIC_BASE` doesn't represent the state of the local APIC.

I'm going to rewrite my code to use MSRs, but I was able to test my existing code by setting my x2APIC to use the xAPIC's interface (i.e. use memory-mapped registers instead). This can be done by setting the `nox2apic` kernel parameter.